# How to map a coordinate to a word in word2vec

Tags: deep-learning, text-classification, word2vec

In word2vec, it's common to map a word in dictionary to a coordinate in an N-dimension space. Is there any way to reverse this process and synthesize a word given any position in the space?

Comment: This is called "finding nearest neighbor" at the query point.

Answer (score 1):

When going from coordinates to word it's not necessary that there would be a vector embedding at the coordinates you are looking at. One way can be to search for the closest vector and return the corresponding word.
Say you have "cat" represented by [1,2,4], "dog" by [2,1,6]  and so on.

```
index2word = ["cat","dog","crow","owl"]     
vecArray=[[1,2,4],
          [2,1,6],
          [9,1,5],
          [4,6,2]]
query=[2,1,7]     #the vector whose word is required
distance=dot(vecArray,query)
```

Find index of minimum element of distance array. Use it to get word from index2word array.

Answer (score 0):

You could code your n-dimension-coordinate as string and compare them with your coordinate string.